# JSON_TABLE not giving expected result when using where clause in oracle 12c

Tags: json, oracle12c

If you see below query:

```
SELECT value1, value2
FROM json_table('["content", "duration"]', '$[*]'
COLUMNS (value1 PATH '$'
)
),json_table('["check"]', '$[*]'
COLUMNS (value2 PATH '$'
)
)
```

It will return 2 rows as result:

```
Value1  Value2

content  check

duration check
```

When I put a where clause and filter for "content" as below:

```
SELECT value1, value2
FROM json_table('["content", "duration"]', '$[*]'
COLUMNS (value1 PATH '$'
)
),json_table('["check"]', '$[*]'
COLUMNS (value2 PATH '$'
)
)
where value1 = 'content'
```

it gives one row as result:

```
Value1  Value2

content  check
```

But if I filter using duration it doesn't return any row. I am expecting one row to be returned. Any idea what is wrong here?

```
SELECT value1, value2
FROM json_table('["content", "duration"]', '$[*]'
COLUMNS (value1 PATH '$'
)
),json_table('["check"]', '$[*]'
COLUMNS (value2 PATH '$'
)
)
where value1 = 'duration'
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. You should probably raise a service request with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in 12.1.0.2.
It is fixed in 12.2.0.1.
It *may* be fixed in a patch set. Have you installed the latest Bundle Patch Set?